# C/C++ GUI framework to create distinctive window style

Tags: user-interface

Can someone please tell me a GUI framework (for Windows. doesn't need to be cross platform) that allows me to specify the design of the UI elements very precisely?

For example, the Windows and UI elements of Adobe products look different than other Windows applications.

I'm looking for a framework that would allow me to create a GUI in that style - or any other style I invent, from the shape of the window, to the visual appearance of any scrollbar, button minimize/maximize buttons and so on.

any recommendations?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/products) or [Gtk](http://www.gtk.org/) spring to mind (both free).

I've used Qt, which is highly customizable. Check their demo app to see what I'm talking about - the defaults look like Windows, but you can change the appearance in any way you see fit. 
They also have a nifty set of examples of desktop applications using Qt: http://qt.nokia.com/qt-in-use/target/desktop

Comment: I already looked at the Qt examples. but they all seem to inherit the currently set default style for windows appearance

Comment: Just because almost no-one does it doesn't mean you can't style Qt to "not look like windows". You can even remove the window frame in Qt (no minimize/maximize/close buttons) if you so desire (QDialogs with the Popup flag). The Qt styling is done via style sheets which are remarkably similar to CSS style sheets: you can do almost anything you want with them.

Comment: @genesys: the Qt Graphics View and Animation Framework allow you to create whatever you wish, really. It's only up to your artistic skills

Answer (score 0):

Qt is the best. Just use it and you'll vote for it too!
Sources and installation instructions : http://cantstopgeeking.blogspot.in/2014/02/start-GUI-Cplusplus-qt.html

Answer (score 0):

Definitly QT, Its easy to learn too! -(You can even drag and drop if your feeling lazy) -However considering you want to do everything precisely, I doubt you would use that.

Anyway: You can download from here: http://qt-project.org/downloads

Documentation is here: http://qt-project.org/doc/

Pretty cool video tutorials here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6KtOzh0StTc&list=TLjkSh_J-O5WuzqsIDdF994FFW-S36ESwH

Need anything? -Let me know.